# How to play a video file in a vb.net form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, video

How to play a video file in vb.net ?

I need the video to automatically start playing on form load.

Comment: Did you Google.Bing it?? There are lots of tutorials

Comment: Yes I did Google first, but some sites saying you need to by ocx components to do this

Comment: Good Media Player Control tutorial [here](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/304.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using google will show many results.  Here is one that seemed pretty easy to follow:

http://www.mitov.com/html/simple_video_player_in__net.html

Comment: That Link shows how to use VideoLab or VisionLab component in vb.net